# Polymer iron-media-query not working on dom-repeat element

Tags: css, polymer, media-queries

I saw quite a few questions on here about using flexbox and iron-media-query with Polymer but none have really fixed the issue I'm having, which is quite a simple one. I have a dom-repeat template that is displaying paper-card elements vertically when the screen size is less than 600px. I want them to be displayed horizontally as the screen expands larger than 600px, eventually breaking into rows if they don't all fit onto one row, essential becoming a grid of cards. The code below only displays the cards vertically even when the screen is expanded beyond 600px. I can do this in pure CSS but I'm struggling with iron-media-query even after reading the docs and trying the demos.

Update: I tried wrapping the paper-card element in a

```
<template is="dom-if" if="{{wide}}">
```

but that made the firebase-query element stop working.

Here's my code:

```
<!-- this is a custom web component -->

<!-- dependencies -->
<link rel="import" href="../bower_components/polymerfire/firebase-query.html">
<link rel="import" href="../bower_components/paper-card/paper-card.html">
<link rel="import" href="../bower_components/paper-dialog/paper-dialog.html">
<link rel="import" href="../bower_components/iron-flex-layout/iron-flex-layout.html">
<link rel="import" href="../bower_components/iron-media-query/iron-media-query.html">


<dom-module id="browse-events">
    <template>
        <firebase-query
                        id="query-all"
                        path="/events"
                        data="{{events}}">
        </firebase-query>

        <template is="dom-repeat" items="[[events]]" as="event">
            <custom-style>
                <style is="custom-style" include="iron-flex iron-media-query">

                    .flex-dir[wide-layout="wide"] .flexchild {
                        @apply --layout-horizontal;
                    }

                    paper-card {
                        margin: 5%;
                        font-family: Comfortaa, 'Arial Rounded MT Bold', 'Helvetica Rounded', Arial, sans-serif;
                        font-size: 1em;
                        width: 300px;
                    }

                    summary::-webkit-details-marker {
                        display: none;
                    }

                    summary:after {
                        content: "+";
                        font-family: Comfortaa, 'Arial Rounded MT Bold', 'Helvetica Rounded', Arial, sans-serif;
                        font-size: 1.5em;
                    }

                    details[open] summary:after {
                        content: "-";
                    }

                    details p {
                        width: 100%;
                    }

                </style>
            </custom-style>


            <iron-media-query query="(min-width: 600px)" query-matches="{{wide}}"></iron-media-query>  

            <div class="flex-dir" wide-layout$="{{wide}}"> <!-- flex container -->
                <paper-card heading="[[event.title]]"  class="flexchild">
                    <div class="card-content"> 
                        [[event.city]]
                    </div> 
                     <div class="card-content"> 
                        [[event.starttime]]
                    </div> 
                    <div class="card-content"> 
                        [[event.price]]
                    </div> 
                    <div class="card-actions"> 
                        <details>
                            <summary><!-- + icon --></summary>
                            <p>[[event.description]]</p>
                        </details>
                        <script>

                        </script>
                    </div>
                </paper-card>
            </div>
        </template>  <!-- end dom repeat -->
    </template>

    <script>
        Polymer({
            is:'browse-events',
            properties: {
                events: {
                    type: Object 
                }
            }
        });
    </script>
</dom-module>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Why are you putting everything inside `dom-repeat`? `dom-repeat` binds one instance of template content to each object in the provided array. So, it is repeating `styles` and `iron-media-query` as well.

Put your `<style>` just after the `<template>`, then, `<firebase-query`, `<iron-media-query>` and so on.

You will need to import `iron-flex-layout-classes.html`
for the flexbox style. 
Import this:

`<link rel="import" href="../bower_components/iron-flex-layout/iron-flex-layout-classes.html">`

`iron-media-query` is for data binding to a CSS media query. So, no need to include in style. It gives boolean representing whether the page matches that media query. If `wide` is true, it will place an attribute `wide-layout` as on `div` with class flex-dir. You don't need to check `wide-layout="wide"` in css.

Here is the updated code:

```
<dom-module id="browse-events">
<template>
<custom-style>
  <style is="custom-style" include="iron-flex">
    .flex-dir[wide-layout] .flexchild {
      @apply --layout-horizontal;
    }

    paper-card {
      margin: 5%;
      font-family: Comfortaa, 'Arial Rounded MT Bold', 'Helvetica Rounded', Arial, sans-serif;
      font-size: 1em;
      width: 300px;
    }

    summary::-webkit-details-marker {
      display: none;
    }

    summary:after {
      content: "+";
      font-family: Comfortaa, 'Arial Rounded MT Bold', 'Helvetica Rounded', Arial, sans-serif;
      font-size: 1.5em;
    }

    details[open] summary:after {
      content: "-";
    }

    details p {
      width: 100%;
    }
  </style>
</custom-style>

<firebase-query id="query-all" path="/events" data="{{events}}">
</firebase-query>

<iron-media-query query="(min-width: 600px)" query-matches="{{wide}}"></iron-media-query>


<div class="flex-dir" wide-layout$="{{wide}}">
  <!-- flex container -->
  <template is="dom-repeat" items="[[events]]" as="event">
    <paper-card heading="[[event.title]]" class="flexchild">
      <div class="card-content">
        [[event.city]]
      </div>
      <div class="card-content">
        [[event.starttime]]
      </div>
      <div class="card-content">
        [[event.price]]
      </div>
      <div class="card-actions">
        <details>
          <summary>
            <!-- + icon -->
          </summary>
          <p>[[event.description]]</p>
        </details>
        <script>
        </script>
      </div>
    </paper-card>
  </template>
  <!-- end dom repeat -->
</div>

</template>

<script>
 Polymer({
  is: 'browse-events',
  properties: {
    events: {
      type: Object
    }
  }
});
```

Plnkr: http://plnkr.co/edit/jfHNhIHijhMMy7jf90e0

Comment: Thanks this resolved a lot of the issues I was having. I also removed the .flexchild from the first line of the CSS and that made the cards wrap the way I wanted. Cheers!